# How can I clear cookies in Adobe Air application

Tags: cookies, air

Recently I'm writing an Air application which can let user access their Facebook page and upload photos (I'm using [Facebook AS API](http://facebook-actionscript-api.googlecode.com/svn/release/current/docs/index.html)). 
I implemented a log in window using a "HTML" control. Users can input their email and password in this log in window. Everything works well until I find my Air application can always remember the user name log in last time. That's because Air can save cookie automatically (This cookie is shared with Safari on my Mac). I don't like this behavior. How can I delete cookies in Air application or prevent Air saving cookie automatically? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [can not](http://ideas.adobe.com/ct/ct_a_view_idea.bix?c=9D564F43-979A-4E35-AA21-85A61B6AB8DE&idea_id=4701F3A3-E370-4CC0-B42B-30E6E27698FD) clear cookie
But you can [manage](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/net/URLRequest.html#manageCookies) it.

Also can be useful: http://hybridhacking.com/node/19

Comment: Hi Lex,
Thanks a lot for your answer. I also know "manageCookie" property in URLReques. But, I can't set it as "false" because if I do this, users can't login to Facebook in my air application. Similarly, if you disable cookies in your browser, you can't login to Facebook either. Because Facebook needs cookie support:(

Comment: Do you know about FacebookDesktop.manageSession property? Look, for example, you turn off manageCookie for URLRequest, set FacebookDesktop.manageSession to false and store yourself any session data in any available local storage. Thus your app doesn't depend on your system.

Comment: Hi Lex, I tried your steps but it doesn't work... manageCookie can't be turned off. If I turned off manageCookie, I will receive an error message from Facebook which ask me to open "cookie" support when log in Facebook using my air app; I also tried to set FacebookDesktop.manageSession property to false and the problem still exists. Now the only solution is clear cookies of facebook.com in Safari manually :(  Anyway, Thank you very much.

Comment: OK. What about set 'user' and 'pass' text fields to emty string in OnLoad event of html document or HTML.complete event in AIR app (depends on your app behavior and current log-in status)?

Comment: I solved this issue by setting "URLRequestDefaults.manageCookie" dynamically. First I set "manageCookie"'s default value as true. If Facebook remembered the last account name and user wants to switch to another account to log in, I will set "manageCookie" to false and reload the Facebook login page. As cookie is disabled this time, the last "account name" is cleared when a new log in page is loaded. Thus the user can input some other account. After this page is loaded, reset "manageCookie" back to true to make sure user can log in Facebook successfully. Thanks Lex very much.